# In what way contact force will develop in a body of mass M kg pressing the ground by 500N and theta degree with horizontal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Will the contact force develop perpendicular to the ground or along the leg?
And yes if the leg was perpendicular to the ground, contact force would obviously have been perpendicular to it.
Here, the leg is on the ground but it is making angle with the horizontal.

I know that the contact force develops between objects in contact, but i am confused about whether or not, contact force depends on orientation of the object. So, what are f and r in the following figure?

[image: Figure from my book.]

Answer (score 0):

Contact force (normal force) is always perpendicular to surface on which the force is applied. It never depends on orientation.

Comment: So what are f and R forces?

Answer (score 0):

There are two forces: the normal force (which is, not surprisingly, normal to the surface) and friction, which is directed forward in this case (when the horse is moving forward). These two forces are components of the total force $R$ with which the ground acts on the horse.

Comment: exactly, horses pushes ground

Comment: ...with f and ground pushes back with R. Can we call these forces "contact force".

Comment: @ManishYadav: Looks like that (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_force , where they say that normal force and friction are contact forces)

Comment: Well thank you. however i got it finally https://youtu.be/ma9Y97hrsb4?t=160 at 2:40

Answer (score 0):

Everything i needed to answer this is available here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ma9Y97hrsb4 to be more accurate at 2:40 the scene provides perfect response.

And Reaction force (R) has two components, Vertical component as (Normal reaction) and horizontal component as friction(if exists).